# Stacked bar plot in R with ratio line overplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have data with one observation per row:

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
mydf <- data.frame(kind = sample(c("good", "bad"), 100, replace = TRUE), var1 = sample(c("yes", "no", "yes"), 100, replace = TRUE), var2 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 100, replace = TRUE), var3 = sample(c( "yes", "no"), 100, replace = TRUE), var4 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "NA"), 100, replace = TRUE), var5 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "NA"), 100, replace = TRUE), var6 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "NA"), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

I need to: make a stacked bar chart with side-by-side bar pairs, one bar for each kind (good vs bad), showing the count of how many of each kind have 0 "yes" vars, how many have 1 "yes" var, etc., up to "yes" for all 6 vars. Y-axis = count, X-axis = the seven categories (0 yes vars, 1 yes var, etc). Each bar should be a stacked bar color-coded showing the contribution of each var to the total height of the bar. NAs are treated as "no". Also, overplot line showing the ratio of count(good)/count(bad) for each of the seven X-axis categories

Comment: Please show us the your expected output, it's much easier to understand than a plot description. It can be a similar graph or one drawn by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, here's what I understand what you're trying to achieve. It consists of three steps:

1. Replace all NA's with "no".
2. Add up all the "yes" in a row-wise manner.
3. Actually plotting the graph.

So address each point.

Lets assume that your data is as follows:

```
mydf <- data.frame(kind = sample(c("good", "bad"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var1 = sample(c("yes", "no", "yes"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var2 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var3 = sample(c( "yes", "no"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var4 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", NA), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var5 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", NA), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var6 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", NA), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

**1**

To replace all NA's with "no" would simply be:

```
mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- "no"
```

here we are searching through the data.frame and replace all `na` with no's using the assignment operator.

**2**

To add everything in a row-wise manner I used the `apply` function. Within the apply function you can use `?apply` to determine the arguments, but in a nutshell, you (1st arg) simply specify the `data.frame`, (2nd arg) specify the direction, 1, for row-wise and 2 for column-wise, (3rd arg) specify the function you wish to apply to the direction.

```
mydf$total.yes <- apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {
  return(length(x[x=="yes"]))
})
```

**3**

Lastly the plot. The easiest and aesthetic way to produce plot is to use `ggplot`. Install it by typeing `install.packages("ggplot2")`. For the bar plots I will refer to this [documentation](here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html), otherwise the code would look like the following.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mydf, aes(total.yes, fill=kind)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

which will produce the plot below:

[image]

I hope this answers the questions you were after. The full code is as follows:

```
mydf <- data.frame(kind = sample(c("good", "bad"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var1 = sample(c("yes", "no", "yes"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var2 = sample(c("yes", "no"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var3 = sample(c( "yes", "no"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var4 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", NA), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var5 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", NA), 100, replace = TRUE), 
                   var6 = sample(c( "yes", "no", "yes", "no", NA), 100, replace = TRUE))

library(ggplot2)

# replace all NA values to no, this step seems redundant because you're only 
# counting yes's
mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- "no"

# for each row figure out how many "yes" there are...
mydf$total.yes <- apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {
  return(length(x[x=="yes"]))
})

# see example here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html
#using your data


ggplot(mydf, aes(total.yes, fill=kind)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

---

`geom_bar` is actually stacked by default, (see [documentation](here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html), if it is stacked it will look something like the following:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(total.yes, fill=kind)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very close to the final needed result. The only thing missing is the stacked part so that viewer can see the relative contribution of each variable to the height of the graph. So each bar should consist of differently colored sections

Comment: Sorry I was not clear - the stacking is intended to show, in each category, which of the vars are contributing to the height of the bar. So each var would have a color (eg var1=red var2=orange var3=yellow var4=blue var5=green var6=violet). In the chart under yes = 2, if the total bar height for the "good" was 15, and in that group it was mainly var3 and var5 and a few var6 that were "yes", the bar would have yellow, green and violet bands showing this, with band thickness proportional to the frequencies of var3, var5 and var6 (and any other vars contributing). I will try to make an example.

Comment: I think the graphs should be easy to create based on the geom_bar documentation, you simply have to massage your data into the format that you want. You probably have to just aggregate all the information to the appropriate levels, and have your X axis as the groupings (e.g. "0 - Good", "0 - Bad", "1 - Good", ...) and then your bar graph will follow

Comment: I have an image of plot made by hand in excel but not sure how to post. Thanks will try to work with the data.